# Android Library Project to Obfuscated JAR

Tags: android, eclipse, obfuscation, proguard, library-project

I have a huge android library project. And I have to obfuscate a class that extended from a view.

I cant understand proguard using. How should I do? Can you describe step by step should I need do?

Answer (score 1):

The Android SDK doesn't obfuscate library projects as such, only complete applications (including their libraries).

You can however run ProGuard yourself, with a configuration like the example in the ProGuard manual > Examples > [A typical library](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#library).

Answer (score 0):

i think your question is pretty similar to stackoverflow question...Refer this Question .............[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531187/android-and-obfuscation)   i'm sure u will find some useful steps and may be answer also........

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531187/android-and-obfuscation

Comment: There are a lot of topic about Android and obfuscation. They explain how to obfuscate APK.  I need obfuscate android library project to JAR. I cant find any Resolved Question